# Attaching Jolokia to kafka brokers deployed using Strimzi operator

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, jolokia

I am deploying a kafka cluster on Kubernetes using Strimzi kafka operator. I need to be able to query Kafka JMX MBEANS remotely  through HTTP/REST using Jolokia (Jolokia is an agent that converts and exposes JMX MBEAN measurements for querying over HTTP…).

AFAIK, Strimzi documentation does not  provide any hint on how to attach Jolokia to kafka brokers. Hence can you please provide a hint on what kind of modifications to the deployment files (strimzi operator and/or cluster deployment files) so that Jolokia is attached to the brokers/Zookeeper instances.

Answer (score 1):

Last I checked, Strimzi offers Prometheus JMX Exporter already, not Jolokia. Prometheus also offers Mbeans over HTTP. https://strimzi.io/docs/operators/latest/overview.html#metrics-overview_str

But the concept is the same, and the fact you're using Strimzi doesn't really matter, since the process is the same regardless of how Kafka is running - you need that JVM agent added into `KAFKA_OPTS`  environment variable. You might want to use a custom docker image that has the Jolokia agent available